# ng-disabled function call is going in infinite loop under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, mongoose

I am populating a table from a collection using ng-repeat, in this I have a check box which I want to make disable is certain condition return true. However, my function is going in a infinite loop when I load the page.

This is my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in seriesList track by $index">
    <td><input id="id{{$index+1}}" class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkNumbersExitsForSeries(s.series_name)" ng-model="s.selected" ng-click="tickCheck(s, s.selected)">
        <label for="id{{$index+1}}" class="checkbox-custom-label">&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td class="mailbox-name" style="width:350px;">{{s.series_name}}</td>
    <td><input type="button" ng-click="editSeries(s)" value="Edit" name="edit" class="btn btn-info" /></td>
</tr>
```

Below is myfunction 'checkNumbersExitsForSeries' in angular controller:

```
 $scope.checkNumbersExitsForSeries= function(series_name){
    console.log("in");

     var params = {
                'seriesName': series_name
            };

    $http.post('/admin/checkNumbersExistsForSeries', params, options)
    .then(function successCallback(response){
    if(response.data.success)    
    {
        console.log("response");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        console.log("no response");
        return false;
    }

    },function errorCallback(response){
        if(response.status = '401')
            $window.location = "#/login"
    });
};
```

Below code is my node controller:

```
exports.checkNumbersExistsForSeries = function(req, res)
{
    numberRegisterModel.find({series:req.body.seriesName, status:{$ne:'deleted'}}, function(err, data){
        if(data){
            console.log("got it");
            res.json({success:true, data1:data});
        }
        else{
            console.log("not got it");
            console.log("error :" + err);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never bind a directive to a function doing a resource call. The digest cycle runs frequently and this will cause your application to issue tons of requests.

Your `checkNumbersExitsForSeries()` function does exactly that. The solution is to iterate `seriesList` upon loading it from the backend, then call `checkNumbersExitsForSeries()` for each entry (or even make it a batch call) and store the results in a hash keyed by the items in `seriesList`.

Comment: any alternate solution for it?

Comment: As outlined in the second paragraph.

Comment: sry, i dont know much, can you tell me how to store in a hash keyed by the items in seriesList?

Comment: Add the code that fills `seriesList` from your backend and I'll try. And an example of a JSON structure that#s the same as your seriesList

Comment: $scope.getAllSeries = function(){
        $http.get('/admin/viewSeries', options)
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            if(response.data){
                $scope.seriesList = response.data; 
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            if(response.status == "401")
                $window.location = "#/login"
        });    
    };

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b9b5bfa5db99241527dd96"),
    "series_name" : "GA-03-C",
    "status" : "added",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: That's invalid JSON, the part `ObjectId("56b9b5bfa5db99241527dd96")` cannot be expressed like this.

Comment: It's still invalid. Here you can see it in action: https://jsbin.com/rofelexine/edit?html,js,console,output. You need to get rid of this `ObjectId()` or enclose it in ""